# Character match in OBIE

Tags: obiee

I am trying to create a metric in OBIEE using the following formular but getting a syntax error. any help will be appreciated.

```
COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN  "Application Event Details"."XNAME" IN ('Hired - External') AND "Job Information"."Title" LIKE '%Intern%' OR  "Job Information"."Title" LIKE ‘%Intership%’  THEN "Application Details"."Pi X" END)
```

Comment: If that is a direct cut-and-paste then your problem is probably the "‘%Intership%’" instead of "'%Intership%'".  Where the difference is the typographic single quotes in your example.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the issue